# Запятые в составных союзах

Tags: пунктуация

Запятая нужна после слова "обращаться" или после слов "в случае"?

Куда обращаться в случае, если нужен достоверный, правильно зарегистрированный перевод стандарта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше оставить представленный вариант: "Куда обращаться в случае, если нужен достоверный, правильно зарегистрированный перевод стандарта?"

Можно считать, что "в случае если" - это составной союз, который автор может расчленять по своему усмотрению. Обычно союз не расчленяется в начале предложения, но расчленяется, если придаточное стоит после главного.

Примеры

В случае если разногласия не могут быть урегулированы путём переговоров, они решаются в соответствии с действующим Российским законодательством в судебном порядке.

Мои наилучшие пожелания тебе в случае, если ты скоро вернёшься домой.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Вера, если придаточное следует за главным, союз не расчленяется. Ср.: [Калугин] рысцой ехал на бастион, с тем чтобы по приказанию генерала передать туда некоторые приказания. Л. Толстой, Севастополь в мае. Подробнее см. в ссылке.

Comment: Я не уверена в однозначности решения, на расчленение много факторов влияют. Без расчленения чисто зависимая связь придаточного от главного. Если расчленяем союз, то появляются взаимообусловленные отношения. Примеры с расчленением: Дедушка приказал не будить Танюшу до тех пор, пока она сама не проснется. Я пригласил вас, господа, с тем, чтобы сообщить пренеприятное известие. Левину хотелось, чтобы солнце не взошло прежде, чем он дойдёт до болота.

Comment: Вера, во всех приведенных вами примерах есть  отрицание **не**, которое влияет на расчленение союза. Лишь в одном примере, где отсутствует отрицание, составной союз расчленен по воли автора, которой желал, видимо, подчеркнуть, что ударение падает на союз.

Comment: См.[Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134)

Answer (score 1):

В составном союзе ***в случае если***  запятая может ставится либо перед составным союзом, либо между его частями.

Запятая может ставится между его частями, если важно подчеркнуть , что ударение падает на союз. 
Запятая может ставится пере всем союзом, если придаточное следует за главным. 
В вашем примере решение за вами. Хотя лучше запятую поставить перед составным союзом. 
Подробнее об этом можете прочитать здесь:[в случае(,) если / когда](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=653.lVgnXNn2r5Rz123JD1pF7ibmisHhrazhOQUasOBraLJBroJTGl6lWA_Uo9YR7T-5tRJaJGoS4ZBJN4I03Zvg5f2vqV7lmRrimLXabyJicAR4MfqF2odzxs8fd2mRVvOTjWA7iXSJW0HwJfvI31UiMg.30a150e29b4c71b938483e1540a58a5b15ec8364&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9bb4iM1VPfe4W5x0C0-qwflIRTTifi6VAA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxa0VXemt0ZlRIeFVpSURkQkdyQ1dNSUQwV1V3cE1WTDRFSEFDQW1YZEdnWEI2NnE5WWVTcFRweDdrLXlGWGJHLTl0ZkVPUGo3c2ZmYlVQdWJRY0xWOGNmWDZDVUx6NnlXVGpiTWcxcE51TGJCa0ZUR2FuNUh6M1VTTnpmcVdpZ1NrZzVlTklIQmR1VUR6MzZndjFzNnh4UXRPal9sWDEtMm1udHBTN0VKc2I3WlptZjVWYUVQSWw4b2wyY29peG9CYWdtd2xqSW04ZmtfSjRhOTBZMmJ2enRreWw2UnA3ajBta0NzWnVlRDhSZmpDZXVNLTRvZkF0MS0xMVBETWNFUzh4TmpDd1dha3FsVHJaTDFqdzd5N0d5Qjg5Ni0xeUtIZXRNV2NDV1pYWEdoVEI0UlF6cnJvbThlUHQwVVFBYXV5YVU5RFVnYnFrRw&b64e=2&sign=e82736f4c01557c9f01df17607d6aa01&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ7IXge4WdYJQW2jaRogeAnYadH5cq3CWsqLNDm7D-t_WDKLPDERW0byUCP7PXH7i2puFQriytiX60ugXeky2DAOhgGQ0d9IMmXd-_S7z5u5Q0Q4UDdE4SbS-T_XMmtsdR-lcz4uYpxqmvFtFLzgBELYgXLpAzSJNiW45hYJECxi8PM3_T4bQPvUuBQ0eqG4C6y6_Uqqz2x8ww&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHtkusEOiLu3mdB1NJZzO2O7lNhRE9yvhOFzIJpHdP1UJ169MFHMVBY5IhT429thbJ0Wa2i0ximmnIsYAnGkVFhL_eUdrmr9qDRjoL4jMIisoti1Jz4HKm8roP8WoQCrYkK38Oe4Ab2aTVjeD0DsahBUB8k032g3piBzPwzwQdYJQs2UX5WLAaJJKIURpBavUr_jw-CNf-vIvGB0W0ux93j1oT8FzjXZi3J1QTSqqUazXBLYkAa9d_gTuqU3597NuzsgS9lwyMlTwtB0CBolVVvFpA2sbHZBlkVX760QBadZq1smBh_K8dDdzocTNjSwZ0jdej3E6qw9kgy8qsi7w_Bk&l10n=ru&cts=1428582020435&mc=3.189898095464287)